# Brownian motion maximum inequality

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, martingales

I am supposed to show this inequality for a 2 or 3 dimensional Brownian motion:

$\textbf{P}^0\{\sup\limits_{t\leq k}{|B(t)|}\geq\frac{1}{2}\}\leq 2\textbf{P}^0\{{|B(k)|\geq\frac{1}{2}}\}$
(where $\textbf{P}^0$ means the BM is started in zero).

This looks a lot like Doob's maximum inequality to me, but on the RHS there is a probabilty instead of an expectation and also $|B|$ is not a martingale for d=2,3. I think you can fix the last part by just taking $\ln|B|$ and $|B|^{-1}$ instead, but I don't see how to replace the expectation with a probability.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)

Comment: Thanks! But I thought the reflection principle was only applicable to linear Brownian motion? Can I also use it for higher dimensions?

Comment: What is $|B(t)|$ for higher dimensions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean ... it's of course length of the random vector with independent Brownian motions in it's entries. But I don't think $|B(t)|$ is a Brownian motion again, is it ...?

Comment: Is it $\ell_2$ norm?

Comment: Well it's the euclidean norm for a $d$-dimensional vector. The $\ell_2$ norm is a generalisation of the euclidean norm I guess, so yes, it's the $\ell_2$ norm for finite sequences.

Answer (score 1):

For $a>0$ let  $\tau_a:=\inf\{t\ge 0:|B_t|=a\}$. Then
$$
\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t)=\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t,|B_t|\ge a)+\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t,|B_t|< a).\tag{1}
$$

Using the strong Markov property (e.g. Theorem 8.3.7 on page 314 [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf)),
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t,|B_t|< a)&=\mathsf{E}^0[1\{\tau_a\le t\}\mathsf{P}^0(|B_{\tau_a+(t-\tau_a)}|<a\mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau_a})] \\
&=\mathsf{E}^0[1\{\tau_a\le t\}\mathsf{P}^{B_{\tau_a}}(|B_{t-\tau_a}|<a)]\le \frac{1}{2}\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t).\tag{2}
\end{align}

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get
$$
\mathsf{P}^0\left(\sup_{s\le t}|B_t|\ge a\right)=\mathsf{P}^0(\tau_a\le t)\le 2\mathsf{P}^0(|B_t|\ge a).
$$

It remains to verify the last inequality in (2), i.e. for any $x$ with $|x|=a$ and $s\ge 0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}^x(|B_s|<a)\le 1/2.
$$